# create binary plist in Java?

Tags: java, iphone, objective-c, plist

is there a way to create binary plist in Java?

I can only find the open sourced C implementation at: http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550/CFBinaryPList.c

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Java Spring Framework based solution](https://github.com/uddhav/java-plist-serializer) It can be extracted for non-Spring usage.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with Objective-C then check out [Rococoa](http://code.google.com/p/rococoa/). Can't say specifically that it does it but I ran into a while back and it looked like it had some promise.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Preferences API on a mac automatically uses plist files and they are in binary format.  If you create some preferences in Java code and save them, they'll appear in the (user's or system) Library/Preferences as a binary plist file.

If your objective with the plist is to store settings, then you can forget the plist all together and use the Preferences API (which will happen to read and write plist underneath).

I hope that helps.